# firebase deploy not updating html file, not a cache issue

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I'm doing a firebase deploy, but my local file does not match my served file.  I have quadrupal checked the file that's in the deployed directory, I've disabled cache, I've hard reloaded, I've navigated directly to the file, I've made additional changes to the file, I've deployed from my local dev machine and from a clean CI server.

I navigate to `http://localhost:3000/views/tasks.html` and see one html result and then to `https://[my-firebase-url]/views/tasks.html` and see an older html result for the same file.

I've done `firebase deploy --debug` and everything is reported as successful and the file count is correct.  Is there any additional information I can find out myself?  Is there a way to look at the build that's uploaded to firebase mentioned in the debug file?

This has worked every time I've ever done it until now with the same project and file structure.  Any way to troubleshoot this would be awesome.  Thanks!

Comment: I started getting `Error: authentication error` messages intermittently after posting this.  Maybe firebase is just having an issue.

Comment: It indeed looks like there were [issues with Firebase Hosting deploys earlier today](https://status.firebase.google.com/incident/Hosting/17002). They've been resolved since. In general when you have such problems, check the [Firebase status dashboard](https://status.firebase.google.com/) for the latest information.

Comment: Nice, if you want to add this as an answer, I'd be happy to accept it as a way to further troubleshoot.

Comment: It won't help anyone in the future, so I'd rather close this question (which is what I voted for).

Comment: It does provide an additional step to troubleshoot, which was my question.  <shrug>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comment by Frank van Puffelencheck mentioned, checking the Firebase status dashboard for the latest information is an additional step to take.  If I had done that, I would have seen that the firebase deploy service was having issues at the time.

Answer (score 2):

in my case I forgot to build(ng build --prod) the modified project to update the dist folder, which is uploaded on firebase server when deploy

Comment: Such a small thing, such a massive headache! Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

The issue for me was that I did not save the file. As i was working with bracket and seeing the modification, I forgot it.